# how to fetch higher level Asset attribute through relation in thingsboard v 3.4

Tags: javascript

In thingsboard Asset 1 contain Asset2 & it contain Asset 3 & Asset3 contain 1 device ,   Then how to fetch Asset1 attribute using relation if that perticular device is Active.

every asset have email if device one value higher than threshold ,I want to send email notification to the Asset 1 & Asset 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be more concise when asking questions and improve your English, and because of that I will make assumptions in my answer.

You need to build rule chain that is triggered by the generator, since if device is inactive, you don't get any msg and therefore you can't have input msg.

Generator originator should be set to Device you mentioned, and run every X seconds as you wish.

After generator, you should use "originator attributes" rule node and fetch active attribute.

Now you need to check if active is true or false, and you can do that by using "switch" rule node with `return[metadata.ss_active]` code. If that code is not working, you need to parse metadata first with `var parsedMetadata = JSON.parse(metadata);` and after that do `return[parsedMetadata.ss_active]`.

When doing connection to the next rule node, you should use "inactive" as connection, since that will be returned from "switch" rule node.

Connected to the inactive, you need to use "change originator" rule node with settings:

- Related
- To
- 2
- Fetch last level relation only (if you don't need Asset 3)
- Contains (change if you are using some other type of relation)
- Asset

With that you should have 2 output msg's, with originators Asset 1 and Asset 2. After that you need to fetch emails and send them. Tutorial about that is on [Thingsboard send email on alarm](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/send-email/)

Hope all of this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable answer ,
your answer helped me so mush